# UISwipeGestureRecognizer isn't sent to an IBAction method when swiping in the simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I dragged two swipe gestures to an image view in my view controller, one for right swipe and another for left. Then I hooked up both of them to the view controller's header file as an IBAction. I wrote some codes in the IBAction method but the problem is that it never be called when I swipe left/right while running the app. Here is a sample of code:

```c
- (IBAction)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"swiped");
    NSArray *images;

    if (self.selectedRow == 0) {
        images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"w8.JPG",@"w7.JPG",@"w6.JPG",@"w5.JPG",@"w4.JPG",@"w3.JPG", @"w2.JPG", @"w1.JPG" ,@"w9.JPG", nil];

        UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection direction = [(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender direction];

        switch (direction) {
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:
                imageIndex++;
                break;
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft:
                imageIndex--;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        imageIndex = (imageIndex < 0) ? ([images count] - 1): imageIndex % [images count];
        self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:imageIndex]];
    }
}
```

The NSLog has never been shown, so I am sure that the sender is not sent to the method.
Another thing is that I used to run the same code in Xcode 5 and everything was OK, recently I have updated my Xcode to the version 6.
What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: I just dragged a swipe to right and connected to a IBAction. It worked fine for me. Check your connection or re-add your swipe gesture's

Comment: Do you use `UIScrollArea` and its zoom functionality? iOS version? If answer is yes and iOS8 then I have same issue. The swipe is blocked if zoom fits content to scroll area. If you zoom out a bit more it will start work (this is IOS8 bug). It did work for me in iOS7.

Comment: I don't use UIScrollArea but my deployment target is iOS 8.1. I changed it to iOS 7.1 and I still had the same problem.

Comment: Do you have two swipe gestures recognizer or only one?

Comment: @lulian Popescu  I have two swipe gestures but I hooked both of them to only one IBAction named handleSwipe.

Comment: Then check the direction of gestures. My default direction was right so the left gesture recognizer was never called. Maybe for you is up or down and this is why your gesture recognizer isn't called.

Comment: @lulian Popescu I just checked them, one of them is right and another is left. The problem is still exist.

Comment: Last idea is to check your connections. Make sure that your ViewController's view contains the gestures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what the problem was. In the image view's attribute inspector, "user interaction enabled" was unchecked, I enabled it. now swipe gesture works fine.